# Boosting the probability of success(random projections, johnson lindenstrauss)

Tags: machine-learning, randomized-algorithms, data-streams, data-mining

In the simple proof of the johnson lindenstrauss lemma written by Sanjoy Dasgupta, Anupam Gupta that can be found [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Edasgupta/papers/jl.pdf) they state the following (p.$62$):

> Repeating this projection $O(n)$ times can boost the success probability to the desired constant, giving us the claimed randomized polynomial time algorithm.

My idea is to see that the success probability of a single trial is $1/n$ thus the success probability of atleast one trial out of $n$ trials is $1 - (1/n)^n$ if we then set it to be larger than $0.95$ we end up with:
$0.05 > (1 - 1/n)^n$ thus $\log(0.05) > n\log(1 - 1/n)$ but i think this way of proving it is wrong.

Could someone help me bring some clarity into this?

Answer (score 3):

If the probability of success of an event is $1/n$, then the failure probability is $(1 - 1/n)$. Hence the probability of failure for $n$ independent trials is $(1 - 1/n)^n$. The limit as $n$ goes to infinity is exactly $e^{-1}$. Therefore, thinking of repeating it $n$ times as another subroutine, if we repeat this subroutine $c$ times we get a success probability of $e^{-c}$ which can be made an arbitrarily small constant.